# can getRedirectLoginHelper open mobile app if user have mobile phone?

Tags: facebook, sdk, mobile-safari, facebook-login, mobile-chrome

This question is usually not understood by developers when I ask about this... I often get "I don't understand the question"...

I will try my best by explaining the context first.

In website there is a possibility to add "login with facebook" button.
The normal flow is

1- user arrives to example.com with a "login with facebook" button.

2- when user click that button, there is a facebook popup

```
2a- if user already logged in with facebook -> the poup ask "app permission" -> goes back to example.com logged in

2b- if user is not logged in facebook -> the popup ask to login, etc
```

--- this flow is ok for desktop because users normally uses chrome or safari to use facebook

**** **The problem in mobile phone**, it that users don't use chrome or safari, they install facebook app

--- This flow in mobile phone "breaks" the one click aspect of it and users get discouraged because they usually DONT remember their facebook password :(

••••• with this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/howto/example_facebook_login/ -->> it dont recognize is user in mobile or desktop by default

QUESTION : with getRedirectLoginHelper : is there a way or code to add to make open facebook app when user is in chrome/safari mobile ????

to achieve this flow
[image]

I tried with javascript but it don't open facebook app

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js"></script>
<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email"></fb:login-button>
```

and console log says

> You are overriding current access token, that means some other app is
>   expecting different access token and you will probably break things.
>   Please consider passing access_token directly to API parameters
>   instead of overriding the global settings.

with php, it's also the same "stay in chrome"

```
include('facebook/vendor/autoload.php');
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([ 'app_id' => ....
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
```

so is it possible to open facebook app when user have mobile phone ? if yes how ?

Thanks

Comment: No that is not possible. If it was the SDK would automatically do that because it would be a better experience.

Comment: @WizKid an other example stackoverflow.com have it's own button "login with facebook" when I open chrome in my mobile phone and type stackoverflow.com -> I click  "login with facebook" and it doesn't open the facebook app, it stays in chrome. From my point of view this flow IS detrimental for user experience.

Comment: Agree. You have to complain to Apple to make it possible

Comment: @WizKid a complain to Apple or Facebook in this case ?

Comment: Apple. It is not possible to do so how would Facebook do it?

Comment: @WizKid in Apple and Android -->> deeplink schemes make this possible, so my best guest would be the SDK to modify... deeplink example whatsapp://parameters -->> this make whatsapp open....

Comment: Sure you can open the Facebook app. There is no way to pass data back to the website that open the app is my understanding.